# Decode Django session cookie value

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am setting a session cookie through `JavaScript` like this:

```
$('.content li a').on('click', function(e) {
        $.cookie.json = true;
        var cookie_value = {postid: 1234, commentid: 8999};
        $.cookie('my_cookie_key', cookie_value, {path: '/'});
    });
```

When I try to retrieve the cookie value in Python Django, I get an encode string like this:
`'"%7B%22postid%22%3A1234%2C%22commentid%22%3A8999%7D"'`

using `request.COOKIES.get('my_cookie_key')`

How can I turn it into a `dict` object so I can easily retrieve all the values in the cookie like `my_cookie_obj.postid`? I have tried decoding the string but I don't think I am doing it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value is simply percent encoded.  Just use the appropriate decoding function, [`unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) from `urllib.parse` (`urlparse.unquote`/[`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) for Python 2 in the original answer) and you should get back what was originally stored.

```
>>> import json
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> s = unquote("%7B%22postid%22%3A1234%2C%22commentid%22%3A8999%7D")
>>> s
'{"postid":1234,"commentid":8999}'
>>> v = json.loads(s)
>>> v['commentid']
8999
```

Do note that users can manipulate all cookie values, so do take care when parsing/using the values as they are untrusted content.